# Most recent transaction date against a Works Order?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies in advance for what will probably be a very stupid question but I've been using Google to teach myself SQL after making the move from years of using Crystal Reports.

We have Works Orders which can have numerous transactions against them. I want to find the most recent one and have it returned against the Works Order number (which is a unique ID)? I attempted to use MAX but that just returns whatever the Transaction Date for that record is.

I think my struggles may be caused by a lack of understanding of grouping in SQL. In Crystal it was just 'choose what to group by' but for some reason in SQL I seem to be forced to group by all selected fields.

My ultimate goal is to be able to compare the planned end date of the Works Order ("we need to finish this job by then") vs when the last transaction was booked against the Works Order, so that I can create an OTIF KPI.

I've attached an image of what I'm currently seeing in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and below is my attempt at the query.

```
SELECT wip.WO.WO_No
     , wip.WO.WO_Type
     , stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Part_No
     , stock.Stock_Trans_Types.Description
     , stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Qty_Change
     , stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Trans_Date
     , wip.WO.End_Date
     , wip.WO.Qty - wip.WO.Qty_Stored AS 'Qty remaining'
     , MAX(stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Trans_Date) AS 'Last Production Receipt'

FROM stock.Stock_Trans_Log 
INNER JOIN production.Part 
ON stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Part_No = production.Part.Part_No 
INNER JOIN wip.WO 
ON stock.Stock_Trans_Log.WO_No = wip.WO.WO_No 
INNER JOIN stock.Stock_Trans_Types 
ON stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Tran_Type = stock.Stock_Trans_Types.Type
WHERE (stock.Stock_Trans_Types.Type = 10) 
AND (stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Store_Code <> 'BI')
GROUP BY wip.WO.WO_No
       , wip.WO.WO_Type
       , stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Part_No
       , stock.Stock_Trans_Types.Description
       , stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Qty_Change
       , stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Trans_Date
       , wip.WO.End_Date
       , wip.WO.Qty - wip.WO.Qty_Stored
HAVING (stock.Stock_Trans_Log.Part_No BETWEEN N'2Z' AND N'9A')
```

[Query + results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uuOX.png)

Comment: From what you are saying all of the joins, etc, that you are showing aren't relevant to the actual problem you have?  Would the following paraphrase be correct?  `stock_trans_log` has many records per `WO_No`, you only need one record per `WO_No`, identified as being the one with the highest `Trans_Date`?  *(Then you join all the rest of the tables on...)*  This link may help identify what to include in your question, and what to remove...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MatBailie. Your summary of my problem is accurate, however I do need the other tables and fields for further filtering and calculations. In effect I'm trying to translate a Crystal Report I have into an SQL View so that I can use it as a data link in Excel. Apologies, I am new to this site and only a week or so into using SQL Server.

Comment: That's why I said `(Then you join all the rest of the tables on...)` :)

Answer (score 0):

If my paraphrase is correct, you could use something along the following lines...

```
WITH
  sequenced_filtered_stock_trans_log AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WO_No
                           ORDER BY Trans_Date DESC)   AS reversed_sequence_id
  FROM
    stock.Stock_Trans_Log
  WHERE
        Type        = 10
    AND Store_Code <> 'BI'
    AND Part_No    BETWEEN N'2Z' AND N'9A'
)
SELECT
  <stuff>
FROM
  sequenced_filtered_stock_trans_log   AS stock_trans_log
INNER JOIN
  <your joins>
WHERE
  stock_trans_log.reversed_sequence_id = 1
```

First, this will apply the `WHERE` clause to filter the log table.

After the `WHERE` clause is applied, a sequence id is calculated.  Restarting from one for each partition *(each `WO_No`)*, and starting from the highest `Trans_Date`.

Finally, that can be used in your outer query with a `WHERE` clause that specifies that you only want the records with sequence id one, this it the most recent row per `WO_No`.  The rest of the joins on to that table would proceed as normal.

If there is any other filtering that should be done *(through joins or any other means)* that should all be done ***before*** the application of the `ROW_NUMBER()`.